# Completely hide div if it is shown partially

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, stylesheet

I have a bar `container` with multiple `divs` inside. Some div like `.first` would have enough width to show all inside text. But some like `.third` only show text partially.

I would like to:

1. Show the parent divs (`.first`, `.second`, `.third`,...) regardless of width
2. But the `.text` div must only visible if it's shown fully. If a part of it is overflow, then it must be completely invisible.
3. All the parent divs have various width & flexible. I don't know and cannot assign fixed width because there could be more. The hard part is the text within them.
4. CSS preferred before I want to use .js as last resort

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/paYuV/3/

[image]

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE 1:**

**Justification (Why):** This is used for a homepage with multiple div/images like this http://www.flickr.com/photos/ishotyourdesign/4636952172/in/photostream/. When mouseover each image, there will be `.text`. But some images won't show in full size (being pushed outside of screen), the text should not show on `hover`. How the `.text` is hidden doesn't really matter as long as users don't see it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? If the page is viewed on someone's phone or tablet, there might never be enough room to show the text and it might never be seen.

Comment: I think Lee Meador is onto something. Why is it, that you would like to hide it? And how should it be hidden? As in pushed below the <div class="second"> </div>, so it isn't visible in the given window - or should it be hidden as in css-style display:none; ?
   I'm not sure why you're trying to do this.

Comment: Hi, I updated with answers above.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/uvHXE/1/

Comment: No, because look like `.third` not showing at all.

Comment: Reading your justification, I think that may be you are missing a point (or it's me ?). If the image has already been pushed away, and the hover is on the image, then the hover won't show, and you just don't need to do anything ?

Comment: @Vals, the images could just show partially depending on browser window. If it's outside the view completely, that won't be an issue (like you said).